# SQL multiple tables count by single field

Tags: sql, mysql, inner-join, having

MySQL / MariaDB structure:

Person

```
| id |
|----|
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
```

```
Car
| person_id | car   |
|-----------|-------|
| 1         | Ford  |
| 2         | Mazda |
| 3         | Ford  |
| 3         | Mazda |
| 3         | BMW   |
```

What query can get the Persons with exactly 1 car, and car is not Mazda ?

expected output is person id 1.

Note:
if GROUP BY is used, query should be full group by, otherwise getting the following error, and changing the SQL configuration is not wanted.
"In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'X'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: You can use the following query: `SELECT Person.id FROM Person JOIN Car ON Person.id = Car.person_id WHERE Car <> 'Mazda' GROUP BY Person.id HAVING COUNT(Person.id) = 1` -- but I think @GMB's query is better & more concise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation and `having` to filter:

```
select person_id
from car
group by person_id
having count(*) = 1              -- has just one car
   and max(car = 'Mazda') = 0    -- which is not a Mazda
```

We can get the result directly from the `car` table. If for some reason you need to bring the corresponding row from `person`, we can `join`:

```
select p.*
from person p
inner join (
    select person_id
    from car
    group by person_id
    having count(*) = 1 and max(car = 'Mazda') = 0
) c on c.person_id = p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, use the negate of the `EXISTS` operator on a correlated subquery as follows:

```
select * -- you may replace * with your columns list
from Car t1 
where car <> 'Mazda' and
  not exists(
  select 1 from Car t2 
  where t1.person_id = t2.person_id and
        t1.car <> t2.car)
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/VP8IOIN5)